# How to create folder in AWS CodeCommit repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, repository, aws-codecommit

I am new to these things.I have created repository in AWS CodeCommit. I want to create a folder in it and upload files using CodeCommit Console. Is it possible? Then how can I do it?

Comment: try to follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-create-file.html#how-to-create-file-console

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can!

From the CodeCommit dashboard, click on your new repository to go to the 'Code' tab. Under your repository description, there should be a 'Add file' dropdown. Choose this, then 'Create file'.

In the 'file name' field, specify the whole path to the file you wish to create. If the specified folders do not exist inside your repository already, they will be created. Fill in the remaining fields and choose 'Commit file'.

Ex) If you want 'src/foo/FooFile.java' in your empty repository, then just use 'src/foo/FooFile.java' and the 'src' and 'foo' folders should be created for you.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!! this helped me.